# Winforms custom control designer

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, designer, windows-forms-designer

I have some custom controls and I am trying to make them appear in the designer, both so that they appear when added to the form with code and so that they can be added to the form using the toolbox.

I have seen for example [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171820.aspx) but it seems ridiculously complicated considering that my custom controls are essentially sets of basic controls grouped together. Visual Studio can show a designer for each of my controls so it seems like I should be able to just force the designer to be recursive shouldn't I?

I read in another SO question (which I have lost the link to...) a much shorter version of that MSDN post which was essentially this part:

```
public override void Initialize(IComponent comp)
    {
        base.Initialize(comp);
        var uc = (ctlAccountClassCode)comp;
        EnableDesignMode(uc.txtCode, "txtCode");
    }
```

I tried this set up in the same manner as the question showed, within a ctlAccoutClassCodeDesigner class and included the same files as the question did but it highlights Initialize and EnableDesignMode claiming that base does not have a definition for Initialize and that EnableDesigneMode does not exist in this context.

I have pretty much no idea what I'm doing here so any help is greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? In code it will *always* exist, and you need to manually add your control to the toolbox

Comment: Um everything basically, I have been having a really hard time finding any information on this. It can draw my custom controls by themselves and it can draw my forms leaving the custom controls blank. It seems like it should be pretty simple to make it draw the custom control on the form but I can't find anything explaining how to do that other than something that is hundreds of lines of code for something that seems like it should be one line or even should be done automatically.

Comment: If you just want to add a user control to a form, that should work out of the box. Without seeing more info, its hard to say where you are going wrong.

Comment: You mean like if you create a new custom control that inherits from user control it will work automatically? Maybe there is something else going on here then, I thought it was normal that that didn't work and I had to enable it somehow... This is my first time using custom controls.

Comment: It should certainly *work* out of the box. It won't show up in the toolbox unless you manually add it.

Comment: I have actually managed to get it to show up in the toolbox in the time since I posted this but it still isn't drawing and although it is in the toolbox it shows an error if I attempt to add one to a form using the toolbox:

System.ArguementException: The property BackColor could not be created from it's default value. Error message: SystemColors.ButtonFace is not a valid value for Int32

I have tried to change the back color but I can't seem to find anything that it will accept...

Comment: No idea what you messed up with that one. :(

Comment: Alright well thanks for your help, at least now I have a new direction to investigate.

Comment: To avoid problems in the designer displaying UCs you may a) move some parts from the constructor to the `InitLayout` event and b) make use of the `if(DesignMode)` checks..